# How to create a link followed by another?

Tags: paypal, discord.py

So currently im coding a bot and in that bot you can buy several other bots and features and i wanted to ask how that works when someone for example clicks my link for paypal and after he pays he will get redirected to the specific bots invite link. Does that even work?

Comment: What's your question exactly?

Comment: Does that even make sense? If other people can invite your bot after a payment you would have to make your bot public. If someone has got the invite link he can simply share it and your business idea would be invalid. (The ID of the bot is enough to invite it.)

Answer (score 0):

When using a link/HTML-only PayPal integration (no API), a return is never guaranteed. PayPal may be obligated to show them a receipt, and they may not click to return, or their browser/user agent may crash or window closed. So, this is a bad option.

What you should do instead is create a website with a PayPal Checkout that integrates via an API. If you have a backend you can do a server-side integration, otherwise you'll have to rely on client-side JS. Here's a simple demo of the latter: https://developer.paypal.com/demo/checkout/#/pattern/client